# Update value in SQL table using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I need to change my field `QB_STATUS` from value `R` to value `C`.  I am doing this in a loop because i cannot "requery" the table as data may have changed.

I have built a list of entries to update.  The code does not error and iterates through 5 times (correct based on my idInvoices list) but the field does not get updated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < idInvoices.Count; i++)
{
    // following command will update one row as ID_Invoice is primary key.  
    // ID_Invoice taken from list previously built in ReadDataToNAVArray
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblINVOICES SET QB_STATUS=@Status WHERE ID_INVOICE = @IDInvoice", myConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", "C");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDInvoice", idInvoices[i]);

    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You forgot `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: You haven't called ExecuteNonQuery method.

Comment: I love this website.  UPVOTES FOR EVERYBODY!! Thanks

Comment: instead of connection to database for every update,you can try updating all at once.Try reading passing datatable to stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **ExecuteNonQuery** in your command.

```
for (int i = 0; i < idInvoices.Count; i++)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblINVOICES SET QB_STATUS=@Status WHERE ID_INVOICE = @IDInvoice", myConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", "C");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDInvoice", idInvoices[i]);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to execute your query: `ExecuteNonQuery`; second - do not create *command*, *parameters* etc within the loop, just assign values and execute:

```
 // Make SQL readable
 String sql =
   @"UPDATE tblINVOICES 
        SET QB_STATUS = @Status 
      WHERE ID_INVOICE = @IDInvoice";

 // wrap IDisposable into "using"
 // do not recreate command in the loop - create it once
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)) {
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar); //TODO: check types, please
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDInvoice", SqlDbType.Decimal); //TODO: check types, please

   // Assign parameters with their values and execute
   for (int i = 0; i < idInvoices.Count; i++) {
     cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = "C";
     cmd.Parameters["@IDInvoice"].Value = idInvoices[i];

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

An example for a different way of using sql commands:

```
SqlConnection addConn = new SqlConnection();
            addConn.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.yourDataBaseConnection;
            addConn.Open();

            SqlCommand addComm = new SqlCommand();
            addComm.Connection = addConn;
            addComm.CommandText = "sql command";
            addComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```